# Java: Transferring File over TCP

Tags: java

I'm in the midst of trying to send a file, and in particular large files, from server to client. I can send small files but atm large files do not work.

Server

```
Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
byte[] data = new byte[(int)myFile.length()];

FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
bis.read(data, 0, data.length);

OutputStream oStream = socket.getOutputStream();
oStream.write(data, 0, data.length);
```

Client

```
byte[] data = new byte[4096];
InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("output.txt");
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

int bytesRead = is.read(data, 0, data.length);
int counter = bytesRead;

// while (-1 != (bytesRead = is.read(data, 0, data.length))) 
// {
//     bos.write(data, 0, bytesRead);
// }

bos.write(data, 0, bytesRead);
```

With this code i'm able to transfer a simple text file successfully. With the commented out section uncommented (and excluding the last line) i thought i'd still be able to send a simple text file and in addition large files like a 200mb video. Obviously, it failed and here i am. Hope someone could give me a hand.

EDIT: Error with while loop (and no last line) is that nothing is written in the txt file

Comment: Please elaborate more about how it no longer works. Do you get an exception? etc

Comment: If you uncomment the commented out section, and drop the last line, then your first read call is never written to bos? ie: you do read, loop [ read, write ]

Comment: With the while loop and the the last line not being called, there's nothing in the output.txt. What's expected is "12345" (which is what's in the file of input).

Comment: @toolkit ahh i just realised what you meant. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the first read and the last write and just use the code that is commented out. That's the only code that actually works.